# Page isn't reloading after redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header, buffer, reload

I am working on a website with a simple login script. The situation is like that:

On the frontpage(`index.php`) the user logs in using a login form, which is then evaluated in `login.php`. If the data isn't correct, the user is redirected back to the homepage, where an error message should be shown, saved in `$_SESSION['error']`. After the showing the message, the variable is unset to make sure it's only shown once (not again if the user would reload the page). And just fyi, the whole site is buffered with the `ob_*` functions.

The problem now is that after the redirect back to the frontpage(if the password is wrong, for example), it isn't reloading the page but instead showing the old version, like there would have been no request or answer at all. The problem has to be server-side, because also the error-text isn't shown until I manually reload(therefore the code hasn't been executed a second time before).

I also tried deleted the buffer before redirect

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Location: " . HOME);
```

or setting the caching in the header with:

```
header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
```

(which of course is client-side, but I tried it anyways).

Does anybody know HOW to fix this or WHY this is happening?

Thanks in advance

**Login-Redirect:**(`login.php`)

```
//other code
if (!PwHash::check_password($db_password, $input['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['error_type'] = 'login';
    header("Location: " . HOME);    //HOME holds the default path
    exit;
} else {
    //other code
```

**Error Output:**(`index.php`)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error']) AND $_SESSION['error'] == TRUE) {
    //error output
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, I should add some more details. Yes, Error reporting is set for all errors and warnings and No, I get none of them.
Also, there shouldn't be a problem with either buffer or session, at least not with the setup. Both files begin like this and nothing is sent to the client before the header() statement:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting by "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors');" it can said something like "headers already send"

Comment: Are you sure your session is started correctly?

Comment: why not use meta redirect ... i hope that my suggestion isn't off-topic ... also, what about error reporting ? what do they say ?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure the following:

```
1-You do session_start();
2-No output was sent to buffer before you session_start();
3-No output was sent to buffer before header();
```

Then debug your code by adding

```
ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I concur, turn your errors on so you can be resourceful in your development endeavors.

Comment: I checked 1 and 2. 3 shouldn't be a problem, because the header isn't hindered by the buffer, only if it is sent. and there is none sent.
I also did set error_reporting, but get no notice of anything.